# magento 2: how to set category as homepage

Tags: magento2, category, layered-navigation

I have tried displaying particular category products on homepage with widget through back-end. It does work. But i want to have layered navigation on left side as it comes in category product list page. Can i set a category page as homepage with layered navigation?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not an out of the box feature of Magento 2. But with custom development, this would be possible. `cms_index_index.xml` layout handler is the one to deal with

Comment: can you give some further details on that?